# How to average multiple columns using Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking to get the average value across multiple columns on a related model, something like this:

```
$this->reviews()->avg('communication', 'friendliness')
```

Where communication and friendliness are an array of column names. However it appears the aggregate functions only support single column names, so I'm doing this:

```
$attributes = array('communication', 'friendliness');
$score = array();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
{
    $score[] = $this->reviews()->avg($attribute);
}

return round(array_sum($score) / sizeof($attributes), 1);
```

Which results in multiple queries. Any suggestions for a best practice here?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid multiple queries you can use a [raw database expression](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions) within [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) as shown below:

```php
$averages = $this->reviews()
    ->select(DB::raw('avg(communication) c, avg(friendliness) f'))
    ->first();

echo $averages->c;
echo $averages->f;
```

Since the aggregate function name `avg` is recognized by all supported database by Laravel, this will not be a big deal.

Comment: Great, thanks - little typo on DB:raw, should be DB::raw - cheers